# How to get the Prediction Score in a HttpResponseMessage provided by a Azure ML Web Service?

Tags: c#, cortana-intelligence, azure-machine-learning-service

So I am currently working with an Azure Machine Learning experiment. I was able to create a model and post it as a web service. I was also able to get the response using the sample request/response code in C# provided in the API documentation that was generated when I created the web service.

My problem is, the response provided by the web service contains many information (a long string of info) including the Prediction Score which is the only thing I need for my C# application. The only thing that comes in mind is to use string manipulation methods in order to extract the info I want. But I think there's a better way than that. I am new to HTTP Request/Response, so please elaborate answers and explanations about it.

Here's my code:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", scoreRequest);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
}

else
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The request failed with status code: {0}", response.StatusCode));

    // Print the headers - they include the requert ID and the timestamp, which are useful for debugging the failure
    Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToString());

    string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
}
```

Here is the Response Message:

```
{"Results":{"output1":{"type":"table","value":{"ColumnNames":["clump_thickness","size_uniformity","shape_uniformity","marginal_adhesion","epithelial_size","bare_nucleoli","bland_chromatin","normal_nucleoli","mitoses","Scored Labels","Scored Probabilities"],"ColumnTypes":["Int32","Int32","Int32","Int32","Int32","Nullable`1","Int32","Int32","Int32","Double","Double"],"Values":[["10","10","4","8","1","8","3","10","1","1","0.979712069034576"],["10","10","4","8","1","8","3","10","1","1","0.979712069034576"]]}}}}
```

I only want the value within "Values":[[...]], which in this case, the 9th index or "1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use project columns in your AML experiment. Currently, you have a module connected to Web Service Output. Use a `project columns` module before your `web service output` to select just the columns you would like to send to our output instead.

Comment: Oh yeah, that idea slipped on my mind. Thanks! That solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can uncheck "append columns" property of score module as shown below. This will then only generate labels and probability column

[image: Score Module with only score labels and probabilities]